# Jupyter notebook crashes when trying to create a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a data frame where the rows are the result of vectorization of a list of stories and the columns are the words in those stories.

the end goal is to predict gender of the writer of each story

```
vec = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vec.fit_transform(df_train["story"].tolist())
```

the problem is - every time I try to run the following line the notebook crashes, no error or anything...

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train.toarray(), columns=vec.get_feature_names())
```

this code worked with different data on a different exercise...

Answer (score 0):

The `X_train.toarray()` method changes the type of the spare matrix (containing only the non null entries) outputed by your **CountVectorizer** to a dense one (full of zeros), which can be hundred of times bigger. Your error is most likely a memory error.

I would suggest you only print the top vocabulary (for instance the top 100 words).

```py
n_words=100
print(
   pd.DataFrame(
      data=X_train[:, :n_words].toarray(), 
      columns=vec.get_feature_names()[:n_words]
    )
)
```

Comment: I cannot do that. but oddly enough, writing it the way you did and 'limiting' it to the exact number of words (in the tens of thousands) worked!